# app.xml consistently overwritten

Tags: ios, flash

I am building an IOS app using Flash Professional 5.5.

The building goes fine, however, I am needing to edit the app.xml file to make a couple of things work. When I do this, save it and then publish the app, the app.xml file is overwritten and the changes I made are gone.

How do I get Flash to keep using the app.xml file I have created rather than it rebuilding a new one every time I publish the app?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, related to this other issue: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/909/cpsid_90916.html. I followed the tutorial many times, but every time the file was overwritten and I could not publish with AIR. How I solved: **I changed the contents of the file the way I needed, then I write-protected the file (then I compiled again)**. This way, Flash could not overwrite it anymore.